# FIO Output Parser for Windows

Tags: windows, parsing, testing, storage, windows-server-2012

I am using FIO http://bluestop.org/fio/ to perform some storage tests on a Windows server. But I need help parsing the output from these tests. Has anyone used anything to parse or visualise the FIO output files? If so please could you share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **--minimal** option. Output headers may be found here https://github.com/amarao/fio_minimal_csv_header